# how to get a users @facebook.com email?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, message, messaging

I am trying to find out if a user has an @facebook.com email for messaging but can not see where to request that  I do request perms for their regular email and can get that, but can't see where to get their @facebook.com email.  It's not included in https://graph.facebook.com/me/ and since there's no guarantee that they have set one up I can't assume that it's based on their username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user has a facebook.com email address it will be their {username}@facebook.com.  However, just because a user has a username setup, doesn't mean there's a corresponding email for it. I've had a username since Facebook landrushed them, and just the other day I setup an email for it.  There's no way to tell if they've set it up.  Your best bet is to ask the user for an email address that your app can use.

Comment: Thanks DCMS.  That's kind of what I was thinking as well, although I was hoping to find a way to know if the user had set that up or now.  I am getting their regular email, but was hoping to get their facebook.com email as well.  I'll leave this question open a little longer in the hopes that someone knows of a way to see if a user has set up their facebook.com email.

Comment: Another option is to send a welcome email to it and see if it bounces.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your privacy settings and from there act as you are editing you email address then there is a Facebook email button setup there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ihab, but maybe I should have been more clear.  I want to get their @facebook.com email through the api.  Ideally at the time they are connecting with my app.